# 2 RACCommands so that one is disabled while other is executing and vice versa

Tags: ios, objective-c, reactive-cocoa

How can I create 2 `RACCommand`s so that one is disabled while other is executing and **vice versa**?

Like so,

```
_prevTrackCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled: [_nextTrackCommand.executing not] signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id _) {}];

_nextTrackCommand = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled: [_prevTrackCommand.executing not] signalBlock:^RACSignal *(id _) {}];
```

but this code will not work as `_nextTrackCommand` is `nil` by the point `_prevTrackCommand` initilized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `RACSubject` that can function as a `RACSignal` but allows you to manually forward events:

```
RACSubject* commandAActive = [RACSubject subject];
RACSubject* commandBActive = [RACSubject subject];

RACCommand* commandA = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:[commandBActive not]
                                        signalBlock:^RACSignal * _Nonnull(id  _Nullable input) {
    // block
}];
RACCommand* commandB = [[RACCommand alloc] initWithEnabled:[commandAActive not]
                                    signalBlock:^RACSignal * _Nonnull(id  _Nullable input) {
   // block
}];

[commandA.executing subscribeNext:^(NSNumber * _Nullable x) {
    [commandAActive sendNext:x];
}];
[commandB.executing subscribeNext:^(NSNumber * _Nullable x) {
    [commandBActive sendNext:x];
}];
```

Comment: This sounds as an idea. Do I need to send `RACSubject` a completed event when command ends execution, so that other command becomes active? Does the subject block command whole time it was sent next and have not received completed yet? Do I need to recreate subject each time it was sent a completed event?

Comment: @kerd No, you don't need to handle `start` and `completed` events because the `executing` stream is handling this. For you, `RACSubject* commandAActive` will be the same as `commandA.executing`.